# How to know that how many Dynamically HTML controls created in from?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form where my system create 3 new HTML controls when user input anydata in textfield and hit enter-key. but now problem is how php will know that how many HTML controls are created dynamically?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <b>Objectives</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <b>Status</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <b>Compl. %</b>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="mboTable">
                <div id="mboName" class="col-sm-5"></div>
                <div id="mboState" class="col-sm-4"></div>
                <div id="mboProgress" class="col-sm-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" id="mboNameInput"  class="form-control " onkeydown="addMbo(this.value)" placeholder="Your MBO...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript Function:

```
$(function() {
var $id = 1;
$("#mboNameInput").on("keydown", function(e) {

if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $nameDiv= $("#mboName");
    var $stateDiv= $("#mboState");
    var $progressDiv= $("#mboProgress");


    $nameDiv.append($("<input/>").attr("type","text").attr("value",$(this).val()).attr('class','form-control').attr('name','Mbo' + $id));
    $stateDiv.append($("<select/>").attr('class','form-control').attr('name','State' + $id).append($("<option/>").text("InProgress")).append($("<option/>").text("Completed")).append($("<option/>").text("Canceled")));
   $progressDiv.append($("<input/>").attr('class','form-control').attr("type","text").attr('name','Progress' + $id));
   $id++;
    $(this).val('');
    }

    });

    });
```

[here its JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1oytwzaa/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is this:
HTMl:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="controlnum" name="controlnum">
```

Javascript
inside the if statment:

```
$('#controlnum').val($id);
```

Comment: you mean i need to add hidden field and i should increment its value by 1 on each new created element? @Provie9